# jquery-chosen drop down field is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am develop my first ajax, jquery-chosen application and I am getting furious with a problem that bothers me for some days. I am trying to populate a chosen dropdown dynamically. The first drop down (1-automarke) populates correctly the second one (2-automodell) shows nothing:

**HTML Code:**

```
<table>
        <tr>        
            <td align="Left" valign="center"><p>Automarke ausw&auml;hlen</p></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="center">
            <select data-placeholder="Bitte w&auml;hlen sie eine Automarke" id="1-automarke">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr> 
            <td align="Left"><p>Automodell ausw&auml;hlen</p></td>
            <td align="Left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
            <select data-placeholder="Bitte w&auml;hlen sie ein Automodell aus" id="2-automodell">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$.getJSON(baseUrl()+'index.php?option=com_xy& ... &format=raw',{key:val},function(r){

        if (val == "Automarke") {
            $("#1-automarke").empty();
            $("#1-automarke").append('<option></option>');
        } else if (arrayVal[0] == "1-automarke") {
            $("#2-automodell").empty();
            $("#2-automodell").append('<option></option>');                 
        }


        //read key and values 
        $.each(r.items,function(k,v){               
            console.log(val+" - key:"+k+" value:"+v);
            if (val == "Automarke") {
                $("#1-automarke").append('<option value="'+k+'"'+connection+'>'+k+'</option>');
            } else if (arrayVal[0] == "1-automarke") {
                $("#2-automodell").append('<option value="'+k+'"'+connection+'>'+k+'</option>');        
            }

        });


        if (val == "Automarke") {       
            $("#1-automarke").trigger("liszt:updated");                 
            $("#1-automarke").prop("disabled", false);                                  
        } else if (arrayVal[0] == "1-automarke") {

            $("#2-automodell").trigger("liszt:updated");                    
            $("#2-automodell").prop("disabled", false);         

        }               

        refreshSelects();
```

After selecting a value from the first drop down (id="1-automarke") I get this result for the first field (id="1-automarke") which is fine:

**HTML result id="1-automarke":**

```
  <td valign="center">
  <select id="1-automarke" data-placeholder="Bitte wählen sie eine Automarke" style="display:     none;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Abarth">Abarth</option>
  <option value="Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="Bentley">Bentley</option>
    ...
    </select>
    <div id="1_automarke_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 300px;" title="">
    <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
    <span>Audi</span>
    <div>
    <b></b>
    </div>
    </a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
    <div class="chosen-search">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <ul class="chosen-results">
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Abarth</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Alfa Romeo</li>
    <li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Audi</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Bentley</li>
    ...
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
```

and this code for the second field (id="2-automdell") where the `<ul class="chosen-results"></ul>` part ist empty:

**HTML result id="2-automdell":**

```
<td>
<select id="2-automodell" data-placeholder="Bitte wählen sie ein Automodell aus" style="display: none;">
<option></option>
<option value="80">80</option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="A2">A2</option>
<option value="A3">A3</option>
<option value="A4">A4</option>
<option value="A5">A5</option>
<option value="A6">A6</option>
<option value="A7">A7</option>
<option value="A8">A8</option>
</select>
<div id="2_automodell_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 300px;" title="">
<a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1">
<span>Bitte wählen sie ein Automodell aus</span>
<div>
<b></b>
</div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
<div class="chosen-search">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
</div>
<ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

The AJAX part works fine, but I have no idea why the `<ul class="chosen-results"></ul>` is empty. Any help is welcome

Comment: Is the JSON being returned with a correct `Content-type: application/json` header? Another option, is that your JSON being  returned isn't valid (try checking it on http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: Yes, the header is correct. The same json request works fine in other cases. I think I will swith to a standard select field.